# Marklogic - Module /com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy not found

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

MarkLogic version : 9.0.6
Data Hub Frame work : 3.0.0

After successfully initializing data-hub-framework on MarkLogic server, I am trying to deploy a javascript module that has uses dhf.xqy.

```
const dhf = require('/com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy');
```

When I run 'gradle mlLoadModules' command, the build is successful without any errors. But When I run 'gradle mlDeploy' command, getting error ' Module /com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy not found'

```
PS G:\data-hub> gradle mldeploy

> Task :hubPreInstallCheck
com.marklogic.hub.impl.DataHubImpl@113a53ae
Error caught while loading modules, cause: Local message: config/resources 
write failed: Bad Request. Server Message: RE
STAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid customer- 
pref extension: could not parse JavaScript extens
ion customer-pref; please see the server error log for detail XDMP- 
MODNOTFOUND: (function (exports, module, require) { c
onst dhf = require('/com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy'); -- Module 
/com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy not found; customer-pref either i
s not a valid JavaScript module or does not export functions (delete, get, 
put, post)
com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: 
config/resources write failed: Bad Request. Server Message:
RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid customer- 
pref extension: could not parse JavaScript exte
nsion customer-pref; please see the server error log for detail XDMP- 
MODNOTFOUND: (function (exports, module, require) {
const dhf = require('/com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy'); -- Module 
/com.marklogic.hub/dhf.xqy not found; customer-pref either
is not a valid JavaScript module or does not export functions (delete, 
get, put, post)
    at
com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putPostValueImpl
(OkHttpServices.java:2872)
    at 
com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putValue
(OkHttpServices.java:2739)
    at 
com.marklogic.client.impl.ResourceExtensionsImpl.writeServices
(ResourceExtensionsImpl.java:206)
    at 
 com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.
lambda$installService$1(DefaultModulesLoader
.java:452)
    at 
 com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.
lambda$executeTask$5(DefaultModulesLoader.java:545)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 52s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the documentation hasn't caught up with a change that was made a while ago. Use this instead:

```
const dhf = require('/MarkLogic/data-hub-framework/dhf.xqy');
```

You can verify that this is the correct path by looking in `/opt/MarkLogic/Modules/MarkLogic/` (Linux). You'll see a `/data-hub-framework/` directory there. The path you have is from when `dhf.xqy` was a module that shipped with and was deployed by DHF, but that code has been included with MarkLogic since ML version 9.0-5.

I'll file a documentation bug on [DHF's GitHub](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub) to get that updated.

Comment: Deployment worked after I made the code change. Thank You. Still curious on why the mlLoadModules did not catch this error. I was getting the error with mlDeploy.